# Playing In-Project Video in Android App

Tags: android, android-videoview

I'm trying to create and app in which I've a video (d1) in my drawable-mdpi folder. 
I want this video to be played when user launch the application.

This is my first attempt of such kind so not sure how to do it.

My MainActivity.Java OnCreate Method Code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    VideoView vv = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.vv01);
    String uriString = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.d1;
    vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uriString));
    vv.start();
}
```

My Activity_Main.xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <VideoView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/vv01"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm not sure if the URI string path I'm using is correct or not. Please suggest how to achieve it as it's not working at the moment.
Also if possible please suggest how to include play/pause buttons and "Next Video" button that re-directs to a new video.

Comment: Your video file is in drawable folder?

Comment: yes, is this why it's not working ?

Comment: make row folder into res folder and put video file into row folder.

Comment: Hi Dipak, I did as you said but when I create "Row" folder inside "res" this folder is not recognized under R. Is there any way of doing it right ?

Answer (score 1):

You can place video file in `assets` folder and then play it like this

```
vv.setVideoPath("file:///android_asset/d1.avi");    
vv.start();
```

Comment: Hi Vasart, I did what you suggested but it's again saying "Sorry this video can't be played". The format of my video is .mpg Does the extension of the video makes any difference ??

Comment: The problem may be because of video format. Try converting it according to documentation http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#recommendations

Comment: I'm using the recommended video formats only now. .mp4 still same issue.